# Exibir imagem de loading ao trocar atributo src de img usando angular 2+

Tags: javascript, imagem, angular

Estou começando a usando angular 2+ e estou com um pequeno problema

Em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo estou trocando o atirbuto src da imagem por uma variavel que controla a url da imagem q deve ser exibida

Gostaria de exibir uma imagem de loading quando troco o valor do src da imagem, seria algo do tipo

1. Clico para trocar imagem;
2. Inicia a imagem de loading;
3. Imagem que deve ser exibida começa a ser carregada
4. Imagem que deve ser exibida termina de ser carregada
5. Some loading;
6. Imagem aparece onde deve.

Como posso fazer isso ? Existe algum evento que é disparado quando a imagem começa a ser carregada?

**UPDATE 1.**
Fiz algumas alterações consegui algo que está funcional, caso alguém tenha uma solução melhor eu fico grato. segue código

component.html

```
<img src='/assets/img/loading.
     [style.display]="!loading ? 'none' : 'block'"/>

<img [src]="modeloSelecionado.modelo_imagem"
     class="img-responsive"
     [style.display]="loading ? 'none' : 'block'"
     (loadstart)="loading = true"
     (load)="loading = false" />
```

component.ts

```
private _loading: boolean = true;

public get loading(): boolean {
    return this._loading;
}

public set loading(value: boolean) {
    this._loading = value;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, tem como colocar seu código? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas. Atualizei com o código e uma solução momentânea que estou utilizando. Caso conheça uma forma melhor de resolver este problema, fico agradecido :)